# Return Observable from firebase firestore

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, reactive-programming

Hey guys I am new to the reactive style and am having trouble turning a firebase query snapshot into and observable, how would you complete this function ? :

```
    override fun GetAllRiders() : Observable<ArrayList<Rider>> {

    var riders = database.collection(DATABASE_COLLECTION_RIDERS)
    riders.addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, firebaseFirestoreException ->
        val riderList = querySnapshot?.toList()
    }

    return ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create your Observable and use callbacks (like `onNext` or `onError`) to notify that new data came up

```
override fun getAllRiders() = Observable.create { emitter ->
    var riders = database.collection(DATABASE_COLLECTION_RIDERS)

    // here you attach a callback which will be called when .dispose() is called
    // or setDisposable (but only one of them at a time! otherwise you're observable will get disposed while creating)
    emitter.setCancelable { riders.cancel() /* don't remember the specifics :( */ }

    riders.addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, firebaseFirestoreException ->
        if (!emitter.isCancelled) {
            if (firebaseFirestoreException != null) {
                // callback for exceptions. here you can pass your Throwable
                emitter.onError(firebaseFirestoreException)
            } else {
                val riderList = querySnapshot?.toList()

                // Callback which will populate passed data to your .subscribe callback
                emitter.onNext(riderList)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. I encourage you to stick to the [kotlin codestyle](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html). Functions should be named with lowercase first letter ;)